# Starting a new fragment from another fragment using intent-filter(both in same activity)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I am a newbie in fragments. I know that we have to register intent-filters in the parent Activity in order to use it in fragments. My question is I have an activity which consists of 3 fragments.
From one among the 3 fragments I want to start a new fragment(a 4th one) using intent-filters. How can I achieve this. Please Let me know.

Comment: Are you saying you are trying to start a fragment with an Intent? That is not how you start fragments

Comment: no I am not. I want to start a fragment when the intent-filter is triggered. and since intent-filters can be associated with fragments only via activity, I am not able to find a workaround.

Comment: In an activity we use "new Intent(Action.ACTION_PICK);" to start a filter.I want to achieve this from a fragment and start a new fragment as the filter is triggered.Both the fragments would have same parent Activity

Comment: That's because you can't have a fragment without an activity. So I suggest you code an activity and perform the fragment initialization/attachment there.

Comment: Sorry if I am wrong..But then I need to preserve the state of the calling fragment.If I start a new Activity..My previous activity's fragments state wont persist?right?

Comment: Sure it will persist, it would be nonsensical to lose the data of a previous Activity just because you start a new one. That's the point of having multiple Activities between which you originally could navigate with "back" in the first place: by always preserving the state of the previous one.